# Need help with SQL query?

Tags: sql

Here is my query. I need to select only one distinct record for each thread but because I'm returning Highlight its cannot be unique and returns two records for the same tread.

Please help me to modify my query to make it work. Thank you

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Name, T0.ThreadID, (CASE WHEN T0.Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Highlight
FROM Messaging T0
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T0.ThreadID = T1.ThreadID
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T0.UserID = T2.UserID
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T0.ID
WHERE  T0.UserID != 9149 
GROUP BY U.Name, M.ThreadID 
ORDER BY Highlight DESC
```

This query returns result like you can see below

```
Name    ThreadID                                Highlight
Alex    048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8C        1
Andrew  048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8B        0
Alex    048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8C        0



Table T0

RecordID    UserID               ThreadID                                 Status
1           9090                 048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8C     0
2           9149                 048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8C     1
3           9090                 048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8C     1
4           5454                 048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8B     0
5           9149                 048C8E05-422C-491A-880C-AE370194AE8B     0
```

Comment: Venture So if you only want one row for Alex, which Highlight value do you want to `SELECT`? The 0, the 1? The oldest? The Newest?

Comment: yes just one row if at least one 0  highlight true and if not highlight false

Comment: I contend that this question has been answered for standard SQL. What DB are you using where the posted answers don't work? Please post your results for Abe Miessler's answer

Answer (score 2):

I see this question all the time.  You will have to decide which of those values you want.  As @James Hill pointed out you have requested all distinct column sets and that is exactly what you got.

If you don't really want distinct combinations of those values you will need to specify which one to drop.  Commonly people will take MAX or MIN values.  Typically it looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Name, T0.ThreadID, MAX((CASE WHEN T0.Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Highlight
FROM Messaging T0
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T0.ThreadID = T1.ThreadID
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T0.UserID = T2.UserID
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T0.ID
WHERE  T0.UserID != 9149 
GROUP BY U.Name, M.ThreadID 
ORDER BY Highlight DESC
```

You will have to test how that works with the case statement in there, but this is the general idea.

Comment: What three records does it return?

Comment: @Abe Miessler +1 this is the correct answer based on the OP's question. I would clarify by aliasing the aggregate something other than the name of a real column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick *which* value to use for status/highlight if there's more than one. Here's one option - use max():

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Name, T0.ThreadID, max(CASE WHEN T0.Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Highlight
FROM Messaging T0
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T0.ThreadID = T1.ThreadID
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T0.UserID = T2.UserID
INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T0.ID
WHERE  T0.UserID != 9149 
GROUP BY U.Name, M.ThreadID 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

You could use min() or any other aggregate function

Comment: It's returning the same 3 records

Comment: what exact;y do you mean? - there can be only one record per name/thread combo